# Node.js ejs - Difference in routes setting

Tags: node.js, ejs

Node.js ejs - Difference in routes setting

What's the difference in defining the route like

```
// Search
router.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {

});
```

... or like:

```
// Search
router.get('/search/', function(req, res, next) {

});
```

Comment: Have you try running it yourself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference, Express automatically removes any trailing slash

```
  // Setup base URL (no trailing slash)
  req.baseUrl = parentUrl + (removed[removed.length - 1] === '/'
    ? removed.substring(0, removed.length - 1)
    : removed);
```

See source code here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js #306

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, there's no difference at all.
Like in folder structure C:/FOlder_Name and C:/Folder_Name/ both are same.